# SQLAlchemy commit sql execution after iterating through results with fetchall method

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm running into issues with reading results created through OUTPUT statements in SQLAlchemy. I originally had an issue reading the primaryKey of an inserted row, but was able to get it to work using the following code setting autocommit to false:

```
sqlString = """ INSERT INTO workflow.{table}  ({columns})
                OUTPUT Inserted.{primaryKey}
                VALUES ({values})""".format(table=self.table, columns=columns, primaryKey=self.primaryKey, values=values)

    with self.dict_db['engine'].connect().execution_options(autocommit=False) as connection:
      result = connection.execute(sqlString)
      primaryKey = result.fetchone()[0]
      result.cursor.commit()
```

Now I am writing a delete statement where I want to do something similar, however after iterating through my results, the cursor object is set to None so I can no longer commit. I have tried both using a for loop that iterates over `results` and `results.fetchall()` and in both cases I cannot commit because the cursor is None. Here is my code as it stands:

```
    sqlString = """ DELETE FROM workflow.{table} OUTPUT Deleted.{primaryKey} {where} """.format(table=self.table, primaryKey=self.primaryKey, where=whereStatement)

    with self.dict_db['engine'].connect().execution_options(autocommit=False) as connection:
      result = connection.execute(sqlString)
      # cursor exists
      primaryKeyList = [item[0] for item in result.fetchall()]
      # cursor is now None
      result.cursor.commit()
```

The fact that this doesn't work is making me rethink both DB executions. Am I doing something drastically wrong here or is there some small syntax I am missing?

Note: the `self.dict_db['engine']` is created with sqlalchemy create_engine

Answer (score 1):

Create a transaction using the connection (using `connection.begin()` and commit that.

```
with self.dict_db['engine'].connect().execution_options(autocommit=False) as connection:
  txn = connection.begin()
  result = txn.execute(sqlString)
  # I'm not sure a cursor exists here, the result doesn't need one for fetchall()
  primaryKeyList = [item[0] for item in result.fetchall()]
  txn.commit()
```

Even better, the object returned from `connection.begin()` implements the context manager protocol, so you can use this simpler version and be sure the transaction is committed if there is no exception, or rolled back if there is:

```
with self.dict_db['engine'].connect().begin() as connection: 
  # connection here is really a Transaction, but all the connection methods work the same
  result = connection.execute(sqlString)
  primaryKeyList = [item[0] for item in result.fetchall()]
  # transaction is committed as the with block exits
```

See [Using Transactions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#using-transactions) in the SQLAlchemy docs for more details.